# dragleave event is firing on inner childs

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag, droppable

I am trying to use HTML5 drag and drop and make the dropable container to change its style when the draggable element is over it.
the problem is if the dropable container contain inner elements a dragleave events getting fired making the container to lose its style.

as you can see when the draggable element is getting inside the small green box. we lose the red border of the outside div.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.droptarget {
   
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
    margin: 15px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.inner-droptarget {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid green
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<p ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="dragtarget">Drag me!</p>


<div class="droptarget" ondragenter="dragEnter(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

<div class="inner-droptarget">
</div>
</div>


<script>
function dragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
}

function dragEnter(event) {
    if ( event.target.className == "droptarget" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
    }
}

function dragLeave(event) {
    if ( event.target.className == "droptarget" ) {
        event.target.style.border = "";
    }
}


</script>

<p>
The border of the outside div should remain red even if dragging into the green div!
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to ignore `"dragleave"` events that are fired on elements that are contained in `"droptarget"` (for example `"inner-droptarget"`).

To do so, you can detect if the event was fired from a descendant of the drop area. Your handler will look like this:

```
function dragLeave(event) {
    if ( event.target.className == "droptarget" ) && !($('.droptarget').contains(event.fromElement) {
        event.target.style.border = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a counter to solve the problem.When dragenter counter++,when dragleave counter-- and check counter === 0 then do something.

```
// div has an child element
divEl.addEventListen("dragenter",dragEnter)
divEl.addEventListen("dragleave",dragLeave)
counter = 0

function dragEnter(){
 counter++
}

function dragLeave(){
  counter--
  if(counter === 0){
    // then do something
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the `dragleave` event does fire on child elements, which is not usually what you want to react to. So, there are various techniques to detect when a dragleave actually indicates when the user's drag has exited the intended dropzone.

- the technique which involves incrementing and decrementing a counter [doesn't work in Firefox due to an ancient open bug.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=919631)
- the technique which involves `pointer-events: none` leaves the user unable to click buttons inside the dropzone.
- techniques that involves checking for containment often fails when the dropzone contains shadow-dom web components.

The following technique seems to work better. It involves checking if the mouse cursor is outside the viewport or dropzone. I've tested it in Chrome and Firefox.

```js
function dragleave_has_exited_current_target(event: DragEvent) {
  const mouse_is_outside_viewport = !event.relatedTarget || (
    event.clientX === 0 &&
    event.clientY === 0
  )

  if (mouse_is_outside_viewport)
    return true

  const rect = (event.currentTarget as any).getBoundingClientRect()
  const withinX = event.clientX >= rect.left && event.clientX <= rect.right
  const withinY = event.clientY >= rect.top && event.clientY <= rect.bottom
  const mouse_is_outside_current_target = !(withinX && withinY)

  return mouse_is_outside_current_target
}
```

You can make use of this technique in any dragleave listener, like this:

```js
function dragleave(event) {
  if (dragleave_has_exited_current_target(event)) {

    // proceed with your own logic here
    remove_dropzone_indicator()
  }
}
```

Note, that in javascript, `event.currentTarget` is the element upon which you attached the event listener itself -- which means, for this technique to work verbatim, you must attach the dragleave listener directly onto the intended dropzone element.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the inner div during dragging, the event drag enter and then drag leave event is firing. We need a way to mark that you are leaving the outer div and entering the inner div so the border stays red on the outer div.

I can get  both borders to be red, but when you leave its a similar problem, both borders go back to green.

```
<body> 
<p ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="dragtarget">Drag me!</p> 
<div id="myOuterDiv" class="droptarget" ondragenter="dragEnter1(event)" 
ondragleave="dragLeave1(event)" 
ondrop="drop(event)" 
ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
<div id="myInnerDiv" class="inner-droptarget" ondragenter="dragEnter2(event)" 
ondragleave="dragLeave2(event)">
</div>
</div>  
<script>
var inOuter = false;
var inInner = false;
function dragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
}

function dragEnter1(event) { 
    inOuter = true; 
    document.getElementById("myInnerDiv").addEventListener("ondragenter", dragEnter2);
    console.log("entered outer");
    return highlightBorder();
}

function dragLeave1(event) {
console.log("left outer");
    inOuter = false;
    highlightBorder();
    event.preventDefault();
}
function dragEnter2(event) {
    console.log("entered inner");
        inInner = true;
        inOuter = true;
        return highlightBorder();  
        }

function dragLeave2(event) { 
console.log("left inner");
    inInner = false;
    inOuter = true;
    return highlightBorder();

}
function allowDrop(ev) {
    return false;
}
function drop(event) {
var inOuter = false;
var inInner = false;
    document.getElementById("myInnerDiv").style.border ="3px solid green";
    document.getElementById("myOuterDiv").style.border ="3px solid green";
     return false;
}
function highlightBorder() {
if( inInner)
{
    document.getElementById("myInnerDiv").style.border ="3px dotted red"; 
    document.getElementById("myOuterDiv").style.border ="3px dotted red";
    return false;
}
if(!inInner && inOuter)
{
    document.getElementById("myInnerDiv").style.border ="";
    document.getElementById("myOuterDiv").style.border ="3px dotted red";
    return false;
}
 if(!inInner && !inOuter) 
{
    document.getElementById("myInnerDiv").style.border ="";
    document.getElementById("myOuterDiv").style.border ="";
    return false;
}
} 
</script>

<p>
The border of the outside div should remain red even if dragging into the green div!
</p>


</body>
</html>
```